# I am trying to generate two random 3 digit prime numbers and creating a function using RSA methods on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to generate two random 3 digit prime numbers and creating a function using RSA methods in VB.NET.

p, q are randomly generated 3 digit prime numbers

```
Dim p, q As Integer
p = TextBox9.Text
q = TextBox10.Text

'If  CInt(Math.Floor((999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd())) + 100 Mod Prime
```

this is all I have thus far, I am struggling to fully implement it.

- Let n = pq. Calculate n and write it down.
- Calculate ϕ(n) and write it down.
- iv. Pick an integer e ≥ 2 such that gcd
  e, ϕ(n) = 1. This will be used for encrypting messages.
- v. The pair (n, e) is your public key. Make this publicly available to everyone, and anyone can send encrypted messages to you

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Generating a random prime number or generating an encrypted string?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what part of this you're struggling with?  Does TextBox9 & 10 already have the random primes?  Where does the Prime variable come from?  Perhaps have another read over the How to ask top in the help, particularly the homework section I'm guessing

Comment: I have tried to edit your question into an easier-to-read format, but it seems that there is information missing. Please [edit] your question so that someone who cannot see the question you've been given has enough material to write an answer for you.

Comment: I am trying to generate two 3 digit numbers that are also prime.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to generate two 3 digit numbers that are also prime

Take a look at the following code:

```
Public Function GenerateTwoPrimes() As Integer()
    Dim r = From i In Enumerable.Range(100, 999).AsParallel() Where Enumerable.Range(1, CInt(Math.Sqrt(i))).All(Function(j) j = 1 OrElse i Mod j <> 0) Select i
    Dim lst As List(Of Integer) = r.ToList()
    Dim ordered = Enumerable.Range(0, lst.Count - 1)
    Dim rng = New Random()
    Dim arr As Integer() = ordered.OrderBy(Function(c) rng.Next()).ToArray()
    Return New Integer() {lst(arr(0)), lst(arr(1))}
End Function
```

You will get two random 3 digit prime numbers.

For example:
[image]